# How to test a function that throws an Exception object using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, exception, jasmine

Using Jasmine, I would like to write a test that expects that a particular type of exception will be thrown.

I'm using Crockford's recommended way of throwing an exception.

The following code works.

```
describe('toThrow', function() {
    it('checks that the expected exception was thrown by the actual', function() {
      var object = {
        doSomething: function() {
          throw {
            name: 'invalid',
            message: 'Number is invalid'
          }
        }
      };
      expect(object.doSomething).toThrow();
    });
});
```

The question is: How can write this test so that it checks that thrown exception name == 'invalid'?

Answer (score 0):

The name and message can be checked with:

```
expect(object.doSomething).toThrow({ name: 'invalid', message: 'Number is invalid' });
```

The name alone can be checked with a custom matcher. Adapted from the built-in `toThrow`:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toThrowPartial: function() {
            function equals(thrown, expected) {
                for(var k in expected) {
                    if(thrown[k] !== expected[k]) return false
                }
                return true
            }

            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    var result = { pass: false },
                        threw = false,
                        thrown;

                    if (typeof actual != 'function') {
                        throw new Error('Actual is not a Function');
                    }

                    try {
                        actual();
                    } catch (e) {
                        threw = true;
                        thrown = e;
                    }

                    if (!threw) {
                        result.message = 'Expected function to throw an exception.';
                        return result;
                    }

                    if (arguments.length == 1) {
                        result.pass = true;
                        result.message = function() { return 'Expected function not to throw, but it threw ' + JSON.stringify(thrown) + '.'; };

                        return result;
                    }

                    if (equals(thrown, expected)) {
                        result.pass = true;
                        result.message = function() { return 'Expected function not to throw ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + '.'; };
                    } else {
                        result.message = function() { return 'Expected function to throw ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ', but it threw ' +    JSON.stringify(thrown) + '.'; };
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            };
        }
    });
});

describe('toThrow', function() {
    it('checks that the expected exception was thrown by the actual', function() {
        var object = {
            doSomething: function() {
                throw {
                    name: 'invalid',
                    message: 'Number is invalid'
                }
            }
        };
        expect(object.doSomething).toThrowPartial({ name: 'invalid' });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify the object to compare with:

```
expect(object.doSomething).toThrow({name: 'invalid', message: 'Number is invalid'});
```

Comment: Actually, I tried that.  However, a test like this: expect(object.doSomething).toThrow({ name: 'a_different_name', message: 'Number is invalid' }); would also pass